Integrating $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{x+2})}$
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{x+2})}dx$$
I found this on Reddit from someone who said they stumbled upon this from a typo, which turned a simple elementary integral into this. I tried using this integral calculator but it could not find a solution. I then used Mathematica which gave me the solution:
$$\frac{2}{5} \left(\sqrt{x} \sqrt{x+2} (x+1)^{3/2}-\frac{2 \sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x+2}} (x+2)}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{2 i \sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x+2}} \sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x}} E\left[\left.i \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\right]2\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+1}}\right)$$
This is a remarkable solution and I would love some insight as to how I can solve this on my own and come up with this answer. I have no idea how the original integral could involve the imaginary unit let alone the elliptic integral or hyperbolic sine.

This is not an elementary function; we have the elliptic finction marker $E$ in there which is commonplace we we have square roots of cubic polynomials.

But how does one arrive at this nonelementary function in the context of this integral?

$$I=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}\, \sqrt{x+1}\, \sqrt{x+2}}$$
$$x=\sinh ^2(t) \qquad \implies \qquad I=2\int  \frac{dt}{\sqrt{2+\sinh ^2(t)}}$$
$$t=i\,u \qquad \implies \qquad I=2 i \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{2-\sin ^2(u)}}=i \,\sqrt{2}\, F\left(u\left|\frac{1}{2}\right.\right)$$ Back to $t$ and $x$
$$I=2 \,i \,F\left(\left.i\,
   \text{csch}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\right|2\right)$$

Here for this integral I will apply one silly trick. The trick is that I will substitute $\sqrt{x+1}=u$. Which implies $(x+1)=u^{2}$. Therefore, $dx=2udu$. Now let me go to the integral.
Let $$I=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{x+2})}dx$$
Now after substituting $(x+1)=u^{2}$, the integral will be
$$I=\int\frac{2u}{u(\sqrt{u^{2}-1}\sqrt{u^{2}+1})}du$$
$$\implies I=\int\frac{2}{\sqrt{u^{2}-1}\sqrt{u^{2}+1}}du$$
Now $$\implies I=\int\frac{2}{\sqrt{u^{4}-1}}du$$
Therefore $u=\sqrt{\sec\theta}+C$

That's not the final answer, rather $I=\int \sqrt{\sec \theta} d\theta $

How to integrate $\sqrt{\sec(\theta)}$ ?  Actually I am an undergraduate student. So, I really don't know

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4}},dx=F(arcsin(x)|-1)$$
